# Io Language Basics

Tags: iolanguage

I am working on a project on the Io language.   There is very little documentation on the language.   I was hoping that some of you would have input on the following:

- Single Dispatch
- Multiple Dispatch
- Arity Overloading
- Type Overloading
- Property Visibility
- Feature Renaming

What are they?  Can you provide any examples?   Thank you, for any help you can provide.   I have enjoyed what I have learned so far and like the language, but it is quite tough to understand as a beginner.

Comment: user1854212, if you ever come back and see this question (with 16 total rep after a whole year, I doubt it), be more specific. You have an opportunity to ask at least 6 distinct questions, get more rep, and make info on StackOverflow richer regarding the Io language. If I continue on with Io, maybe I'll ask some of these.

Answer (score 1):

- Single Dispatch
- Multiple Dispatch

Io has dynamic dispatch.

- Arity Overloading
- Type Overloading
- Property Visibility
- Feature Renaming

Io can do all these and all properties (at least those stored in slots) are visible.

Comment: The questioner is looking for more a elaborate answer than a re-categorization of the provided list.